# Saving logical output images into a new (mkdir) folder

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I used imresize to resize about 20images. I want the resized images to be stored in a new folder I created. Here is the code I used:

```
imwrite(myoutput, 'resized.png');
```

Now my problem us that, I only get one image written to the working directory, named 'resized.PNG'. I want all the 20 resized images to be saved.

I also want them saved in a new folder defined by mkdir(resizedFolder)... Which I don't know how to do.

Here is an excerpt from my codes:

```
dirD=dir('*.jpeg');
for k=1:length(dirD);  %k=20      %technically
    %i ran a long code to find a       %rectangular boundary, and cropped.

    CropIm=imcrop(I, thisBlobsBoundingBox);
    resizedIm=imresize(CropIm, 0.1);
end
```

Now, I want `resizedIm` to be stored in `resizedFolder` as individual images which should give me 20 images.

Comment: have a look at the `fullfile` and `mkdir` help, if you still have problems come back with all your code from reading to writing

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to combine the directory and filenames. Also you will want to create a custom filename for each image. Below I assume that all of your images are in a cell array.

```
resizedFolder = '/path/to/folder';

% Create folder if it doesn't exist
if ~exist(resizedFolder, 'dir')
    mkdir(resizedFolder);
end

dirD = dir('*.jpeg');

for k = 1:numel(dirD);
    % Your code to get the boundary
    CropIm = imcrop(I, thisBlobsBoundingBox);
    resizedIm = imresize(CropIm, 0.1);

    % Create a custom filename for this image.
    filename = sprintf('resized%02d.png', k);
    imwrite(resizedIm, fullfile(resizedFolder, filename));
end
```

This will create images in the folder that you specify with the filenames being: `resized01.png`, `resized02.png`, ...

**Update**: I have updated my response to be more specific to your initial code.

Comment: Thank you lots guys. Suever I used your help... I got this error message;: [ cell contents reference from a non cell array object]... That's for my output(cropped images). By the way I should have added, that my output variable is Logical. Please how do I make my Logical output a cell array?

Comment: @OgwucheJoseph I don't see an error message in your comment. Please update.

Comment: I am getting error "Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object" ...for myoutput, which is a logical variable that contains cropped image

Comment: @OgwucheJoseph as I said in my answer I assume that your images are a cell array. What are the dimensions of your logical variable? or rather, how do you store 20 of them?

Comment: i did imcrop in a loop for k=20images. When I run the codes... It completes it displaying all images. But when I run imshow it displays only one. Also when I do imwrite it saves only one.

Comment: @OgwucheJoseph if you're doing the crop inside of the loop, then simply replaces `images{k}` above with your output variable and put the cropping code inside of my for loop.

Comment: Question is updated to be more specific to your issue.

Comment: Thank you Suever... I almost didn't notice. U will get back

Comment: Thank you Suever... I almost didn't notice. So I did... It worked, but the resezedFolder is created as a Variable in the workspace. I wanted it created as a sub folder in my current dir. However if I can extract my images from the resizedFolder variable, its still okay. How do I extract my images.

Comment: @OgwucheJoseph If you provide a relative path for the `resizedFolder` variable it will be in the current directory. To extract your images, you'll want  to use `dir` and `imread`. That is really a different question than the one that you've posted here though.

Comment: Oh... I get you, that I am the one to provide a path for the folder to be created. You have really helped me on this one. It worked! Thank you Suever, and everyone. I am grateful.

Comment: @OgwucheJoseph If this solution worked for your problem, consider marking it as the answer to help people who may stumble across this question with Google in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I would store your current directory to a variable like

```
curPath = cd;
newPath = newDirectory;
cd(curPath);
cd newPath;
```

After this, your working directory is the new folder. Run the loop to save your files.

Make sure you are iterating the file names.

```
for i = 1:20
    imwrite(myoutput(i), ['resized', num2str(i),'.png']);
end
```

Comment: It is best to not use `i` or `j` as loop indices in MATLAB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab